# Can others see my email address?

Tags: xbox-network

After the recent dashboard update, I see that the email address linked to my XBox live account flashes across the top right of my dashboard, alternative with my Online Friends/Messages/Gamerscore and my GamerTag.  Can people on my friends list (or everyone) see my email address, or has the GUI just changed to show it to me only?

I've looked at the privacy settings, and checked out some friends profiles and it doesn't seem this information is exposed, but the dashboard has lots of different views and menus, and I'd like to be sure it's not in there somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft privacy policy](http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/fullnotice.mspx#use) says that

> Except as described in this statement, we will not disclose your personal information outside of Microsoft and its controlled subsidiaries and affiliates without your consent.

The document says nowhere that they will share your email, so unless you gave your explicit consent, nobody else will see it.

Comment: Was there no new privacy policy?  I blow by those things pretty fast at this point.

Comment: I edited my answer to have the actual privacy policy, which is the only thing that really matters here.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I believe it enhances the answer :).